# Restart pods when configmap updates in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, configmap

How do I automatically restart Kubernetes pods and pods associated with deployments when their configmap is changed/updated?

---

I know there's been talk about the ability to automatically restart pods when a config maps changes but to my knowledge this is not yet available in Kubernetes 1.2.

So what (I think) I'd like to do is a "rolling restart" of the [deployment](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/) resource associated with the pods consuming the config map. Is it possible, and if so how, to force a rolling restart of a deployment in Kubernetes without changing anything in the actual template? Is this currently the best way to do it or is there a better option?

Comment: `$ kubectl set env deployment my deployment --env="LAST_RESTART=$(date)" --namespace ...` do the job for me

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Signalling a pod on config map update is a feature in the works (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22368).

You can always write a custom pid1 that notices the confimap has changed and restarts your app.

You can also eg: mount the same config map in 2 containers, expose a http health check in the second container that fails if the hash of config map contents changes, and shove that as the liveness probe of the first container (because containers in a pod share the same network namespace). The kubelet will restart your first container for you when the probe fails.

Of course if you don't care about which nodes the pods are on, you can simply delete them and the replication controller will "restart" them for you.

Comment: With "deleting pods" you mean: Collecting all pod names, delete one, wait until replaced, delete second one, wait until replaced etc.  Correct?

Comment: using a deployment I would scale it down and then up.  You will still have that small amount of down time though.  You can do it in one line to reduce that...   `kubectl scale deployment/update-demo --replicas=0; kubectl scale deployment/update-demo --replicas=4;`

Comment: If you don't want to find all the pods, and don't care about downtime - just remove the RC and then re-create the RC.

Comment: Does this mean the volume it’s mounted on is updated and you just need to re-read the file on the pod without restarting the whole pod?

Comment: @NickH Quick and dirty, fortunately the downtime was acceptable in my case and this worked great, thanks!

Comment: To avoid downtime, can we scale it up, say from one replica to 2 and then kill the older instance? Would this approach work?

Comment: @xbmono Only if you kill the second one afterwards.
Otherwise it would only have an instance with the old secret and a new one with the new secret. Ugly mess.
If you want to restart all pods then you have to scale first down and then up as NickH mentioned above.

Comment: Easier to run `kubectl rollout restart deployment/my-deploy` and k8s will manage a rolling restart similar to how updated deploys work. This also works with DaemonSets and StatefulSets

Comment: Yeah a rollout restart is definitely the way to go, it means you maintain HA (rather than scale down then up) and all pods will get new config map / secrets

Answer (score 200):

The current best solution to this problem (referenced deep in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22368 linked in the sibling answer) is to use Deployments, and consider your ConfigMaps to be immutable.

When you want to change your config, create a new ConfigMap with the changes you want to make, and point your deployment at the new ConfigMap. If the new config is broken, the Deployment will refuse to scale down your working ReplicaSet. If the new config works, then your old ReplicaSet will be scaled to 0 replicas and deleted, and new pods will be started with the new config.

Not quite as quick as just editing the ConfigMap in place, but much safer.

Comment: This is the approach we've taken as well

Comment: Worth mentioning that the new experimental tool `kustomize` supports automatically creating a deterministic configmap hash, meaning you don't need to manually create a new configmap: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/12d1771bb349e1523bc546e314da63c684a7faf2/examples/configGeneration.md#L5

Comment: This is what Spinnaker does behind the scenes, so if you use it, you wouldn't have to worry about this.

Comment: and how do we do that ?

Comment: good approach but need to handle deletions of old config maps :(

Comment: @AlokKumarSingh I still don't know of a clean way to handle cleaning up orphaned ConfigMaps. In general deleting orphaned resources is something that's not very well supported in k8s; I don't know of a "define every resource that should be in this namespace" API call. You can try ownerReferences (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/) but I don't see a good way to apply that to ConfigMaps. I have been experimenting with the Argo deployment manager and I believe it will cover this case -- it handles deleting resources that are no longer in your manifests.

Comment: Much cleaner to do this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/51421527/4106031 Chose this answer.

Comment: Label Selectors are immutable, ended up using this and doing the hard work of cleaning the config maps by following conventions on the name, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317003/restart-pods-when-configmap-updates-in-kubernetes/51421527#51421527

Comment: @Symmetric hey adding to your answer on the delete problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/65497844/4106031

Answer (score 82):

The best way I've found to do it is run [Reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader)

It allows you to define configmaps or secrets to watch, when they get updated, a rolling update of your deployment is performed.  Here's an example:

You have a deployment `foo` and a ConfigMap called `foo-configmap`. You want to roll the pods of the deployment every time the configmap is changed.  You need to run Reloader with:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stakater/Reloader/master/deployments/kubernetes/reloader.yaml
```

Then specify this annotation in your deployment:

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    configmap.reloader.stakater.com/reload: "foo-configmap"
  name: foo
...
```

Comment: Reloader is compatible with kubernetes >= 1.9

Comment: But I don't want to roll the pods of the deployment every time the configmap is changed, I want the configmap volume files change silently, not restarting a single pod.

Comment: @SteveWu that already happens https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically but if your running application needs to be signalled or restarted to pick up the updated files, that's what this question is about.

Answer (score 67):

[Helm 3 doc page](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments)

Often times configmaps or secrets are injected as configuration files in containers. Depending on the application a restart may be required should those be updated with a subsequent `helm upgrade`, but if the deployment spec itself didn't change the application keeps running with the old configuration resulting in an inconsistent deployment.

The `sha256sum` function can be used together with the `include` function to ensure a deployments template section is updated if another spec changes:

```
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/secret.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
[...]
```

In my case, for some reasons, `$.Template.BasePath` didn't work but `$.Chart.Name` does:

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: admin-app
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Chart.Name "/templates/" $.Chart.Name "-configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
```

Comment: Not applicable to general Kubernetes usage, only applicable to Helm

Comment: The answer is helpful but probably not relevant to this question

Comment: `helm` 3 was released recently. Thus, the link is outdated. It points to `master` branch. The following URL will lead to (currently) latest `helm` 2 docs: https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/release-2.16/docs/charts_tips_and_tricks.md#automatically-roll-deployments-when-configmaps-or-secrets-change

Comment: Cool solution. I changed to sha1sum, as in my case sha256sum had 65 characters which resulted in `Deployment.apps "xxx" is invalid: metadata.labels: Invalid value: "xxx": must be no more than 63 characters`. Alternative would be `| trunc 63`, but sha1sum should be "more unique".

Comment: Link for helm v3: https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments

Comment: This will not work unless you apply the changes using HELM/ kubectl.

Answer (score 25):

For `k8s` `>` `1.15`, doing a ***rollout restart*** worked best for me as part of CI/CD with App configuration path hooked up with a volume-mount. A reloader plugin or setting `restartPolicy: Always` in deployment manifest YML did not work for me. No application code changes needed, worked for both static assets as well as Microservices.

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment/<deploymentName> -n <namespace>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works on my GKE deploy.

Comment: This worked for me too. In my case, we're using OpenShift and there's an option to "Restart rollout" in their UI which made the change take effect. For me, it's OK that it's not automatic but the "restart rollout" part is the piece I was missing.

Answer (score 17):

You can update a metadata annotation that is not relevant for your deployment. it will trigger a rolling-update

for example:

```yaml
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            configmap-version: 1
```

Comment: I looking docs about metadata:
  labels:
    configmap-version: 1

Comment: metadata label changes do not trigger a restart of the pods

Comment: This answer has upwotes so I need to ask. If we update the metadata, will Kubernetes cluster trigger a rolling update? @maoz-zadok

Comment: I believe this works as long as the metadata label is under `template.spec`

Comment: Confirmed using labels under `spec.template.metadata.labels` works! (have edited the answer it's under review). Really elegant way to do this :+1

Comment: I am getting this error `MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable` when i try to update the selector label, and template metadata label needs to be same as selector label :( this won't work. https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/508

Comment: This can work only when you add the key in the labels and not update it.

Comment: I recommend using an annotation instead of a label, for this approach, since you can freely update annotations, and labels can't be mutated. Or in more recent versions of kubectl can simply call `kubectl rollout restart deployment/mydeployname` to trigger a new rollout of the same config. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-restart-em-

Answer (score 13):

Had this problem where the Deployment was in a sub-chart and the values controlling it were in the parent chart's values file. This is what we used to trigger restart:

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ tpl (toYaml .Values) . | sha256sum }}
```

Obviously this will trigger restart on *any* value change but it works for our situation. What was originally in the child chart would only work if the config.yaml in the child chart itself changed:

```
    checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/config.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Really cool! Use it everywhere :-)

Comment: worked! thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `kustomize` (or `kubectl apply -k`) and then leveraging it's powerful `configMapGenerator` feature. For example, from: https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/configmapgenerator/

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

# Just one example of many...
- name: my-app-config
  literals:
  - JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk
  - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-agentlib:hprof

  # Explanation below...
  - SECRETS_VERSION=1
```

Then simply reference `my-app-config` in your deployments. When building with `kustomize`, it'll automatically find and update references to `my-app-config` with an updated suffix, e.g. `my-app-config-f7mm6mhf59`.

**Bonus, updating secrets:** I also use this technique for forcing a reload of secrets (since they're affected in the same way). While I personally manage my secrets completely separately (using [Mozilla `sops`](https://github.com/mozilla/sops)), you can bundle a config map *alongside* your secrets, so for example in your **deployment**:

```yaml
# ...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app
          image: my-app:tag
          envFrom:
            # For any NON-secret environment variables. Name is automatically updated by Kustomize
            - configMapRef:
                name: my-app-config

            # Defined separately OUTSIDE of Kustomize. Just modify SECRETS_VERSION=[number] in the my-app-config ConfigMap
            # to trigger an update in both the config as well as the secrets (since the pod will get restarted).
            - secretRef:
                name: my-app-secrets
```

Then, just add a variable like `SECRETS_VERSION` into your ConfigMap like I did above. Then, each time you change `my-app-secrets`, just increment the value of `SECRETS_VERSION`, which serves no other purpose except to trigger a change in the `kustomize`'d ConfigMap name, which should *also* result in a restart of your pod. So then it becomes:

Answer (score 3):

**Native Option without Third party**

**Kubernetes** **auto-reload** the **config map** if it's mounted as **volume** (If subpath there it won't work with that).

Example : https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/update-configmap-without-restarting-pod-56801dce3388

**Third-party Option**

> How do I automatically restart Kubernetes pods and pods associated
> with deployments when their configmap is changed/updated?

If you are using configmap as Environment you have to use the external option.

- [Reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader)
- [Kube watcher](https://github.com/kiwigrid/k8s-configmap-watcher)
- [Configurator](https://github.com/gopaddle-io/configurator)

> When a ConfigMap currently consumed in a volume is updated, projected
> keys are eventually updated as well. The kubelet checks whether the
> mounted ConfigMap is fresh on every periodic sync. However, the
> kubelet uses its local cache for getting the current value of the
> ConfigMap. The type of the cache is configurable using the
> ConfigMapAndSecretChangeDetectionStrategy field in the
> KubeletConfiguration struct. A ConfigMap can be either propagated by
> watch (default), ttl-based, or by redirecting all requests directly to
> the API server. As a result, the total delay from the moment when the
> ConfigMap is updated to the moment when new keys are projected to the
> Pod can be as long as the kubelet sync period + cache propagation
> delay, where the cache propagation delay depends on the chosen cache
> type (it equals to watch propagation delay, ttl of cache, or zero
> correspondingly).

Official document : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically

ConfigMaps consumed as environment variables are not updated automatically and require a pod restart.

**Simple example Configmap**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config
  namespace: default
data:
  foo: bar
```

**POD config**

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: configmaptestapp
    image: <Image>
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /config
      name: configmap-data-volume
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
  volumes:
    - name: configmap-data-volume
      configMap:
        name: config
```

Comment: this works, but it sucks: "eventually updated as well" means minutes sometimes

Comment: that's depends on kubelet refresh you can adjust it if you are running your own K8s cluster with managed you won;t be able to do it i guess.

Answer (score 1):

I also banged my head around this problem for some time and wished to solve this in an elegant but quick way.

**Here are my 20 cents**:

- The answer using labels as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51421527/4106031) won't work if you are updating labels. But would work if you always add labels. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51421527/4106031).
- The answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40624029/4106031) is the most elegant way to do this quickly according to me but had the problem of handling deletes. I am adding on to this answer:

### Solution

I am doing this in one of the Kubernetes Operator where only a single task is performed in one reconcilation loop.

- Compute the hash of the config map data. Say it comes as `v2`.
- Create ConfigMap `cm-v2` having labels: `version: v2` and `product: prime` if it does not exist and RETURN. If it exists GO BELOW.
- Find all the Deployments which have the label `product: prime` but do not have `version: v2`, If such deployments are found, DELETE them and  RETURN. ELSE GO BELOW.
- Delete all ConfigMap which has the label `product: prime` but does not have `version: v2` ELSE GO BELOW.
- Create Deployment `deployment-v2` with labels `product: prime` and `version: v2` and having config map attached as `cm-v2` and RETURN, ELSE Do nothing.

That's it! It looks long, but this could be the fastest implementation and is in principle with treating [infrastructure as Cattle](https://www.google.com/search?q=infra+as+cattle+medium&oq=infra+as+cattle+medium&aqs=chrome..69i57.3142j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (immutability).

Also, the above solution works when your Kubernetes Deployment has [Recreate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#recreate-deployment) update strategy. Logic may require little tweaks for other scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the immutable property to the config map totally avoids the problem. Using config hashing helps in a seamless rolling update but it does not help in a rollback. You can take a look at this open-source project - 'Configurator'  - https://github.com/gopaddle-io/configurator.git .'Configurator' works by the following using the custom resources :

1. Configurator ties the deployment lifecycle with the configMap. When
   the config map is updated, a new version is created for that
   configMap. All the deployments that were attached to the configMap
   get a rolling update with the latest configMap version tied to it.
2. When you roll back the deployment to an older version, it bounces to
   configMap version it had before doing the rolling update.

This way you can maintain versions to the config map and facilitate rolling and rollback to your deployment along with the config map.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not kubernetes-style, but works for me - use inotifywait in a separate thread from inside of the container to watch the confimap dir:

inotifywait --recursive --event attrib /opt/config

Answer (score -2):

Another way is to stick it into the command section of the Deployment:

```
...
command: [ "echo", "
  option = value\n
  other_option = value\n
" ]
...
```

Alternatively, to make it more ConfigMap-like, use an additional Deployment that will just host that config in the `command` section and execute `kubectl create` on it while adding an unique 'version' to its name (like calculating a hash of the content) and modifying all the deployments that use that config:

```
...
command: [ "/usr/sbin/kubectl-apply-config.sh", "
  option = value\n
  other_option = value\n
" ]
...
```

I'll probably post `kubectl-apply-config.sh` if it ends up working.

(don't do that; it looks too bad)

Comment: OP wants to know how to update pods when configmap updates have been made. This only states an alternative way to get data into a pod. Not to mention, this technique isn't recommended. Its much better to track configurations in a configmap than pass values via command.

Comment: @phbits well, if exactly that has become possible after half a decade then great. Otherwise pick your workaround.