# Kubernetes: Restart pods when config map values change

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I have a pod with the following specs

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: busybox
    env:
      - name: WATCH_NAMESPACE
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: watch-namespace-config
            key: WATCH_NAMESPACE
  restartPolicy: Always
```

I also created a `ConfigMap`

```
kubectl create configmap watch-namespace-config \
        --from-literal=WATCH_NAMESPACE=dev
```

The pod looks for values in the watch-namespace-config configmap.
When I manually change the configmap values, I want the pod to restart automatically to reflect this change. Checking if that is possible in any way.

Comment: Have you searched? Like: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=restart+pod+configmap+change

Answer (score 3):

This is currently a feature in progress https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22368

For now, use Reloader - https://github.com/stakater/Reloader

It watches if some change happens in ConfigMap and/or Secret; then performs a rolling upgrade on relevant DeploymentConfig, Deployment, Daemonset, Statefulset and Rollout

How to use it - https://github.com/stakater/Reloader#how-to-use-reloader

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned correctly once you update a `ConfigMap` or `Secret` the Deployment/Pod/Stateful set is not updated.

An optional solution for this scenario is to use `Kustomization`.
`Kustomization` generates a unique name every time you update the `ConfigMap/Secret` with a generated hash, for example: ConfigMap-xxxxxx.

If you will will use:

```sh
kubectl kustomize . | kubectl apply -f -
```

`kubectl` will "update" the changes with the new config map values.

### Working Example(s) using `Kustomization`:

https://github.com/nirgeier/KubernetesLabs/tree/master/Labs/08-Kustomization

Comment: Thanks. I wanted the deployment to automatically restart the pods. Guess that won't happen. You either have to do what you mentioned or do a `rollout restart`

Answer (score 0):

Seems Kyverno also has some solution for it: https://kyverno.io/policies/other/res/restart-deployment-on-secret-change/restart-deployment-on-secret-change/

It is basically a policy to restart whenever some identified resource changed. In the linked example it is a secret, but a configmap should work likewise.

Requires to install Kyverno though.

Answer (score -2):

kubectl rollout restart deployment deployment-name

for automatic restart : [configmap change doesn't reflect automatically on respective pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56954670/configmap-change-doesnt-reflect-automatically-on-respective-pods)

Comment: As I said, I want it to automatically roll. and not manually run restart command

Comment: CSUNNY
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56954670/configmap-change-doesnt-reflect-automatically-on-respective-pods