# how to automatically roll deployments in helm when secret being used is created via some other helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3, kubernetes-secrets

I want to automatically roll my deployment when there is a change in the secret being created via the same helm chart. For this I used `sha256sum` function and it worked well. I followed this [Link](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments) for the same.

```
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/secret: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/secret.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
[...]
```

Now; I want to automatically roll my deployment (say, created via chart1) when the secret was created via some other helm chart say, chart2. And whenever there is a change in secret created via chart2 it should roll deployment created via chart1 as well. Secret created via chart2 is mounted to chart1 deployment. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57983530/5099971)