# Updated configMap.yaml but it's not being applied to Kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I'm editing configMap.yaml in my Helm chart, but when I log in to one of my pods to check if it's being applied, it doesn't reflect my changes. I'm fairly new to Helm charts so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your helm chart config?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317003/restart-pods-when-configmap-updates-in-kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

For updating your `ConfigMap` you can also use `kubectl patch` command if you find it more fitting for you. Documentation regarding it can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#patc).

For applying the changes there is a very useful tool called [Reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader).
Reloader can watch changes in `ConfigMap` and `Secret` and do rolling upgrades on `Pods` with their associated `DeploymentConfigs`, `Deployments`, `Daemonsets` and `Statefulsets`.

Please let me know if that helped.

Answer (score -1):

After you edited cm, should restart you pod to reload new value.

1. edit yaml file.
2. `kubectl apply -f cm.yaml`
3. `kubectl delete po your-pod -n your-ns` if controlled by a controller. If just pod, `kubectl delete -f pod.yaml` then `kubectl create -f pod.yaml`.

Comment: When I do this I'm getting a parsing error converting YAML to JSON. It points to a specific line where I'm using a template file to define a name. How do I debug this?

Comment: If you just modified the value, it shouldn't get an error, if you add new k-v, notice the space and quotation marks.