# Helm, add checksum annotation from values

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

A third-party chart which I use a dependency allows extra annotations to be passed in from values file. However the annotation I want to pass in is `checksum/config`

*values.yaml*

```
mychart:
    annotations:
       checksum/config: "{{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}"
```

But whatever passed from the values files is rendered as string. Is there a working way to pass in checsum/config from *values.yaml*?

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59329295/2631728) maybe helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

values.yaml

```
podAnnotations:
  checksum/config: '{{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}'
```

templates/deployment.yaml

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- tpl (toYaml .) $ | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
```

Result:

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: 'd464b243d16631e438f2944569aa390c7d4932d8f36597163fba35d4bd2bddd5'
```

Hope it can help :)

Answer (score 0):

It passed as a String because you added double quotes "" outside the {{}}...
You just need to remove the double quotes.